# Timeout implementation of JPA transactions and Session invalidation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have been handling a application which uses ***wicket+JPA+springs*** technologies.Recently we got many 5XX error in logs(greater than threshhold).During that time,There were some general problems due to unstable response times of the ***mainframe db2*** which is ***backend*** for our application.
But after that once the mainframe is OK this application servers did not come to normal again.

**There are a lot of hanging transactions (from my appplication).**
**There are many  threads  in  the server that may be hung.** 
As users will go on keeping login or will access the links in aplication during that time the situation becomes worse.

When I look at webspehere logs I found following exceptions:

```
00000035 ThreadMonitor W WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 88" (000005ac)
has been active for 637111 milliseconds and may be hung. 
There is/are 43 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
```

In application logs i found following exceptions:

```
-->CouldNotLockPageException: Could not lock page 4. Attempt lasted 3 minutes
-->DefaultExceptionMapper - Connection lost, give up responding.
   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ResponseIOException:
   com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.ClosedConnectionException: OutputStream encountered error during  
   write.
--> JDBCExceptionReporter - [jcc][t4][2030][11211][3.67.27] A communication error occurred
   during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, 
   or socket output stream. 
   Error location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1).  Message: 
   Connection reset. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08001, Error Code = -       4.499
```

Now we are working on the solutions to this problem.The follwing are two solutions that we are thinking as of now.

1.I have gone through many forums and found that whenever we get CouldNotLockPageException then it would be better to invaidate the session and force user to login page.Currently We do not have session invalidation (logout) mechanism.So we will implement that one.

2.**We need to implement transaction timeouts so that we can stop hanging transactions.**

I need solution for this problem from java or server  side.Here we are using ***wicket,jpa and springs frameworks***.I have few queries.

**1.How can we implement transaction timeouts in the above frameworks?**

**2.Will invalidating session can stop hanging transaction or threads that may hung?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using Spring, it's as simple as that:

```
@Transactional(timeout = 300)
```

The Transaction annotation allow you to supply a timeout value(in seconds) and the transaction manager will forward it to the JTA transaction manager or your Data Source connection pool. It works nice with Bitronix Transaction Manager, which automatically picks it up.

You also need to make sure the java.sql.Conenction are always being closed and Transaction are always committed (when all operations succeeded) or rollbacked on failure.

Invalidating the user http session has nothing to do with jdbc connections. Your jdbc connection should always be committed/rollbacked and closed(which in case on connection pooling, will release the connection to the pool).

And make sure the max pool size is not greater than tour db max concurrent connections setting.

Comment: the default for the `timeout` element is -1:  `defaults to the default timeout of the underlying transaction system`. Wouldn't it be easier to specify the default for the underlying transaction system (once for always)? Otherwise it could be so, that many code lines should be changed...

Comment: Also, for Bironix [the default is already 60secs](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Configuration#Configuration-Timerssettings).

Comment: True, but setting the default value is a double edged sword. For intensive processing schedulers it makes sense to increase the transaction timeout, while for most UI driven flows you should struggle to have your transactions running as fast as possible. The slower the queries the longer the locks will be held, the more deadlock probability, the longer the transaction.

Comment: Right you are: that's why the default should be for set to be valid for most of the requests (probably UI requests) and to be set manually to a bigger value for all long schedulers.

Comment: Yes. I just added a randomly chosen value as an example. I raised it to 300 to avoid any missunderstandings.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Thank you very much for your answer.Should we keep '@Transaction' on a method level?Why because,Here we are using ldap for fetching userdetails during login.We have LdapFetch class which is declared as '@Component'.In that class some methods will be there to fetch userdetails.We need to implement timeout on ldap methods so that it will not cause hanging transactions when new users access the application during db2 is unstable.So two questions 1)Should we keep '@timeout' on method level?2)Is it true that timeout implementation will avoid hanging transactions?

Comment: You can look into IBM website for ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001DSRA0010E

Comment: @SudheerKumarS Spring allows you to have a default transaction timeout value (org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager#setDefaultTimeout) that you can override for specific methods (@Transactional). We've already been using this pattern so I see no problem with it.

Comment: You also need to make sure the java.sql.Conenction are always being closed and Transaction are always committed (when all operations succeeded) or rollback on failure.

Comment: @VladMihalcea I have one more doubt.Could you please clarify that invalidating the session of a user can stop hanging transactions of that user requests?

Comment: @Sudheer Invalidating the user http session has nothing to do with jdbc connections. Your jdbc connection should always be committed/rollbacked and closed.

Comment: @SudheerKumarS Check the maxPoolSize, if Spring is used against DBCP check the pool size there. The db2 server refuse connection may be because of the connection pool.

Comment: @zawhtut Thank you very much.Could you please clarify me how does connection pool refuse connection and also maxpoolSize.Please share if you have any article.

Comment: that's simple. just make sure the max pool size is not greater than db2 max concurrent connections setting.

Comment: @SudheerKumarS http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html see the maxTotal properties.

Comment: @VladMihalcea.It is working fine for me in dao classes which have been configured as '@Repository' and we are using  entity manager in those classes for transaction.Now only one class is left i.e Ldaputil class('@component') which will not use entity manager to fetch results in its methods.But it is using webservice call to fetch results(user details).I have tried keeping transaction time out as 1 seond on its methods and also wrote a delay programme for 12 seconds but I am not getting timeout exception.Could please clarify regarding this issue?

Comment: So that LdapUtil ss calling a web service to fetch the data? Where is the web service deployed? Is it configured for transaction timeouts? Is there a timeout set for the web service? It's hard to figure it out with so little data.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Hi,hope you are well.I have one doubt.Can we keep transaction timeout on a application level rather than method level so that entitymanager will take care of all transactions in all methods for the given timeout that has been set in xml file?

Comment: Sure. The default is usually set at the connection pool level, like Bitronix.