# Java Spring DAO hangs on return statement

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, return, dao

I have a Java Spring application with an Oracle DB and Hibernate. In my controller, I'm calling a DAO to retrieve some data. The DAO method proceeds until it reaches the return statement and then it fails to return to the controller. No exception is thrown. Instead, it times out. It's something like this

Controller:

```
 @Autowired
    DAO dao; 

     public @ResponseBody int controller(){
          //stuff     
          System.out.println(1); 
          Map<Long, DBObj> objs = dao.getObjMap(ids); 
          System.out.println(3); 
          //other stuff
     }
```

DAO:

```
@Transactional
 public Map<Long, DBObj> getObjMap(List<Long> ids){
      //stuff
      System.out.println(2)
      return objs; 
 }
```

Output:

```
 1
 2
```

As far as I can tell, it is retrieving from the DB correctly, so it doesn't seem to be a DB issue. Other database calls work fine.

From the debugger, it seems to be hanging somewhere inside the return statement. Specifically, it seems to be hung on SocketInputStream.java while trying to call socketRead0

EDIT: The problem was to do with sorting. I sorted the child objects of the retrieved object. On return, Hibernate was attempting to make additional database calls and hanging as a result. I resolved this by passing the parent object to the calling method and then sorting in the calling method instead of the DAO.

Comment: Since you are in a transaction you could be running into a deadlock or some other query/insert that's just taking too long at the database level.

Comment: I agree with JustinKSU ... does your commit go through? Do you really need a transaction for a read operation?

Comment: Looks like the operations in your getObjMap is taking much time. Could you please share those lines of codes too

Comment: Instead of tracing, you should use debugger to see if method actually finished.

Comment: Right now, I'm testing it on my local environment, so there shouldn't be a deadlock. The database isn't the issue because I can print the retrieved data right before the return statement, and it all looks fine. When I remove the @Transactional, I get "org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here" so it does seem to be necessary

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
@Transactional(
    timeout = 3600,
    rollbackFor = { RuntimeException.class, ApplicationCheckedException.class },
    noRollbackFor = { ApplicationCheckedNoRollbackException.class, InternalNoRollbackException.class })
public @interface LongTx {

    // Empty.

}
```

Annotate your method with @LongTx

```
@LongTx
 public Map<Long, DBObj> getObjMap(List<Long> ids){
      //stuff
      System.out.println(2)
      return objs; 
 }
```

Comment: Just tried this. Doesn't help- it hangs in the same spot. I don't think it's a database issue because other database calls work fine.

Comment: Did you try to debug

Comment: Yes, it is hanging somewhere inside the return statement.

Comment: What are the operations you are doing..like what us the code //stuff in that method. Can you share ?

Comment: Basically, I'm retrieving a list of objects based on a list of ids. Then I put them into a map so I can easily get them by their ids. Before putting them into the map, I do a sort on the children objects of those objects, but that's entirely programmatic and doesn't involve an additional DB call. Should be simple. My hibernate criteria is just "criteria.add(Restrictions.in("ID", ids));"

Comment: "No exception is thrown. Instead, it times out" Do you see a ttansaction timeout exception ?

Comment: I get "Thread "WebContainer : 6" (0000017f) has been active for 677271 milliseconds and may be hung."

Comment: Specifically, it seems to be hung on SocketInputStream.java while trying to call socketRead0

Comment: Please check, if this helps you :                                                                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042528/thread-webcontainer-0-00000029-has-been-active-for-647279-milliseconds-and

Answer (score 0):

Just see to it there is no lock on the Database from say some other transaction, meaning see to it that if there is some lock mechanism used in the code.

There may be some other transaction holding a lock on the records in the table.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no problem with the database. I can call other methods that access the database just fine, even ones that use the same tables.

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753510/timeout-implementation-of-jpa-transactions-and-session-invalidation